# fix grid gap using multiple grid scroll

Tags: html, css, css-grid

see snipets, grids are messy.
final aim is to fix grid gap.

point of grid is the following.

- whole 2nd line of grid is scrollable (without 1st column, because this is header)
- other grids are not scrollable (not display scrollbars)

i don't know how to scroll more than 1 cells.
So, I made child grid inside the main grid.

fortunately, it worked.

but, they have gap between parent grid and child grid.
probably the problem is scrollbar width.

if you interest to solve this problem, please let me know how to solve.
i don't care how to fix it.

if there any technique to scroll more than 1 cells, it would be best solution.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template:
    " morning morning morning morning-detail "  2rem
    " hello hello-detail hello-detail hello-detail " 3rem
    " bye bye bye bye-detail " 2rem /
    3rem 1fr 1fr 1fr
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.hello-detail {
  grid-area: hello-detail;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.hello-detail {
  display: grid;  
  grid-template:
    "area area area" 3rem /
    1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.hello-detail > div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="morning">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="morning">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="morning">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="morning-detail">
    my name is xxx.
  </div>
  <div class="hello">
    def
  </div>
  <div class="hello">
    def
  </div>
  <div class="hello">
    def
  </div>
  <div class="hello-detail">
    <div>
      abc
    </div>
    <div>
      def
    </div>
    <div>
      feg
    </div>
    <div>
      abc
    </div>
    <div>
      def
    </div>
    <div>
      feg
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bye">
    end
  </div>
  <div class="bye">
    end
  </div>
  <div class="bye">
    end
  </div>
  <div class="bye-detail">
    see you again.
  </div>
  <div class="bye-detail">
    see you again.
  </div>
  <div class="bye-detail">
    see you again.
  </div>
</div>
```